HTMX prints the JSON response inside the buttons and textareas
I'm trying to build a HTMX multistep form that sends real time data to an endpoint as it's inserted/clicked.
The problem is, when I select one of the emojis (they're inputs) and type something on the first screen's textarea, it is printed on the second screen textarea, and if I click on the button, it overwrites the content with it's JSON response again.
Here's a print of it:
After clicking on a emoji rating on the first page and typing something on the textarea, the second page looks like this
This is my HTMX body:
<div class="survey-form" id="survey-form">
        {% for question in questions %}
        <div class="question" id="question{{ forloop.counter }}"
            style="{% if not forloop.first %}display: none;{% endif %}">
            <label class="question-label">{{ question.question_text }}</label>

            {% if question.response_model == 'SMF' %}
            <div class="smiley-rating">
                {% for smiley in smileys %}
                <label class="smiley-container">
                    <img src="{% static smiley.imgSrc %}" alt="{{ smiley.altText }}" class="smiley-image"
                        onclick="handleSelection('{{ question.id }}', this, '{{ smiley.value }}');"
                        hx-post="/survey_responses/" hx-trigger="click"
                        hx-vals='javascript:{"survey": surveyId, "external_id": externalId, "responses": responses}'
                        hx-headers='{"X-CSRFToken": "{{ csrf_token }}"}'>
                </label>
                {% endfor %}
            </div>
            {% elif question.response_model == 'SOD' %}
            <div class="satisfaction-rating-centered">
                <button type="button" class="button-style satisfied"
                    onclick="handleSelection('{{ question.id }}', this, 'Satisfeito')" hx-post="/survey_responses/"
                    hx-trigger="click"
                    hx-vals='javascript:{"survey": surveyId, "external_id": externalId, "responses": responses}'
                    hx-headers='{"X-CSRFToken": "{{ csrf_token }}"}'>Estou satisfeito</button>
                <button type="button" class="button-style dissatisfied"
                    onclick="handleSelection('{{ question.id }}', this, 'Insatisfeito')" hx-post="/survey_responses/"
                    hx-trigger="click"
                    hx-vals='javascript:{"survey": surveyId, "external_id": externalId, "responses": responses}'
                    hx-headers='{"X-CSRFToken": "{{ csrf_token }}"}'>Estou insatisfeito</button>
            </div>
            {% elif question.response_model == 'NPS' %}
            <div class="nps-rating">
                {% for item in nps_scale %}
                <button type="button" class="nps-button" style="background-color: {{ item.color }}"
                    onclick="handleSelection('{{ question.id }}', '{{ item.value }}')" hx-post="/survey_responses/"
                    hx-trigger="click"
                    hx-vals='javascript:{"survey": surveyId, "external_id": externalId, "responses": responses}'
                    hx-headers='{"X-CSRFToken": "{{ csrf_token }}"}'>{{ item.value }}</button>
                {% endfor %}
            </div>
            {% elif question.response_model == 'YON' %}
            <div class="yes-no-rating-centered">
                <button type="button" class="button-style yes" onclick="handleSelection('{{ question.id }}', 'Sim')"
                    hx-post="/survey_responses/" hx-trigger="click"
                    hx-vals='javascript:{"survey": surveyId, "external_id": externalId, "responses": responses}'
                    hx-headers='{"X-CSRFToken": "{{ csrf_token }}"}'>Sim</button>
                <button type="button" class="button-style no" onclick="handleSelection('{{ question.id }}', 'Não')"
                    hx-post="/survey_responses/" hx-trigger="click"
                    hx-vals='javascript:{"survey": surveyId, "external_id": externalId, "responses": responses}'
                    hx-headers='{"X-CSRFToken": "{{ csrf_token }}"}'>Não</button>
            </div>
            {% endif %}

            <div>
                <label class="text-area-label">Em poucas palavras, descreva o que motivou esta avaliação</label>
            </div>
            <textarea class="feedback-textarea" onchange="sendTextResponse('{{ question.id }}', this.value)"
                hx-post="/survey_responses/" hx-trigger="change from:.feedback-textarea"
                hx-vals='javascript:{"survey": surveyId, "external_id": externalId, "responses": responses}'
                hx-headers='{"X-CSRFToken": "{{ csrf_token }}"}'></textarea>

            <div class="navigation">
                {% if not forloop.last %}
                <button hx-get="javascript:;" hx-swap="outerHTML" hx-target="#question{{ forloop.counter }}"
                    hx-trigger="click" onclick="showNextQuestion({{ forloop.counter }}, {{ questions|length }})"
                    type="button" class="button-style next-button">Próxima</button>
                {% else %}
                <button type="submit" class="button-style" onclick="window.close();">Enviar</button>
                {% endif %}
            </div>
        </div>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>

    <input type="hidden" id="responses-data" value="{{ responses|safe }}" />

This is my script section:
var externalId = '{{ external_id }}';
        var surveyId = '{{ survey_id }}';
        var responses = {};

        function handleSelection(questionId, element, value) {
            responses[questionId] = { value: value, description: responses[questionId]?.description || '' };

            console.log(externalId)

            // var elements = document.querySelectorAll('.smiley-image, .nps-button, .satisfaction-rating-centered button, .yes-no-rating-centered button');
            var elements = document.querySelectorAll('.question[id="question' + questionId + '"] .smiley-image, .question[id="question' + questionId + '"] .nps-button, .question[id="question' + questionId + '"] .satisfaction-rating-centered button, .question[id="question' + questionId + '"] .yes-no-rating-centered button');
            elements.forEach(function (el) {
                el.style.opacity = '0.3';
                el.disabled = true;
            });
            element.style.opacity = '1';
            element.disabled = false;

            document.getElementById('responses-data').value = JSON.stringify(getCleanedResponses());
        }

        function sendTextResponse(questionId, text) {
            if (!responses[questionId]) responses[questionId] = { value: '' };
            responses[questionId].description = text;
            document.getElementById('responses-data').value = JSON.stringify(getCleanedResponses());
        }

        function getCleanedResponses() {
            var cleanedResponses = {};
            for (var id in responses) {
                if (responses.hasOwnProperty(id)) {
                    cleanedResponses[id] = { value: responses[id].value, description: responses[id].description };
                }
            }
            return cleanedResponses;
        }

        document.body.addEventListener('htmx:beforeRequest', function (event) {
            event.detail.requestConfig.body = JSON.stringify({
                survey: surveyId,
                external_id: externalId,
                responses: getCleanedResponses()
            });
            event.detail.requestConfig.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json';
        });

        function showNextQuestion(current, total) {
            if (current < total) {
                document.getElementById('question' + current).style.display = 'none';
                document.getElementById('question' + (current + 1)).style.display = 'block';
            }
        }

The expected result would be to just send the data to the API and allow the user to enter new data on the next screens.The API is currently receiving the valid data though, but I can't have the damn JSON being exposed on my buttons and textareas...

Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a minimal reproducible example.

When you press the button, it overwrites its content with the response data. Which button? The navigation button to go to the next question? Which element gets overwritten with the response data? The pressed button or the textarea on the second question?
